# MS Word C#: replace fields with values keeping formatting

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

I have a Word document with formatted fields (some of them bold and surroundings are not) of MacroButton type filled with text codes and a dictionary of it's values.

I want to replace all fields with simple text values keeping it's format.

I'm new to VSTO and my code does a replacement but loses formatting (boldness or font size for example).

```
        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "field1", "value1" },
            { "field2", "value2" }
        };
        object selStart = Globals.ThisDocument.Content.Start;
        object selEnd = Globals.ThisDocument.Content.End;
        var fields = Globals.ThisDocument.Range(ref selStart, ref selEnd).Fields;
        foreach(Field field in fields)
        {
            Range range = field.Code;
            string code = range.Text.Split(' ').Last();
            field.Delete();
            range.InsertAfter(values[code]);
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace Fields in Word document with their content using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199323/how-to-replace-fields-in-word-document-with-their-content-using-vba)

Comment: That link may help. What you want to do is use the Word object model and unlink those fields. This converts them to their values.

Comment: That link didn't help. Despite its name, it says how to search and remove fields. I don't understand why do you need to call the search for fields if there is a collection of them. But replacing `field.delete()` with `fields.unlink()` helps as Charles suggested.

Comment: You could try Spire.Doc which is a C# class library for Word documents. It provides the Replace(string matchString, string newValue, bool caseSensitive, bool wholeWord) method to replace text in a Word document with new strings without changing the original formatting. See this documation (https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/NET-Word-Replace-String-in-Word-with-New-String-in-C-VB.NET.html) for more details.